# How to write this rails library requiring respond_to and render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write this library that responds to some json and html request.  In the controller's action, I will call MyLib.search(params).  Then in "module Something; class MyLib", I have "def search(params); respond_to ... render :json ...; end".  If I try to use this library, I get "NoMethodError (undefined method `respond_to' ...".

How should I write this, so that I get respond_to and render in scope?

Comment: `respond_to do |format| format.json do ... render :json => json end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a mixin would serve you better, something like this:

```
module Something
    def search # params will be in scope so no need to pass it
        #...
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json ...
        end
    end
end
```

and then in the controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    include Something
    def whatever
        # ...
        search
    end
end
```

Comment: That's what I wound up doing.